# convert dataframe to netcdf multidimension using python

Tags: dataframe, concurrency, python-xarray, netcdf, lookup-tables

i have a dataframe(df) of 100000 rows. i want to convert to a netcdf. i know the best way is xarray, but my df is bit complicated as follows

```
`*a              b      c     d        e            f*
[1,2,3...n]    4     5     8    [2,3...m]     [m*n matrix] 
[1,2,3...n]    5     5     8    [2,3...m]     [m*n matrix]  
[1,2,3...n]    4     5     10   [2,3...m]     [m*n matrix]   
.....100 k rows`
```

in the above **a** and **e** colomn are always the same for all rows.** b,c,d** colomns are repeatation of the values. now i want to create a netcdf where the attribute f is a 5-dimensional multidimension array of size *m*n*(uniques_values of b)*(uniques_values of c) *(uniques_values of d)*

since the number of rows are too many. it is better to avoid looping and use concurrancey

any good way is helpful,
your text
thanks in advance

i tried using the following but error

`ds = df.set_index(['b', 'c', 'd']).to_xarray()`
`ds.to_netcdf('~/test.nc')`